# How to make UITextField behave similar to banking input format in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to make a TextField like the one that is used in banking apps, where while you're typing the amount of money, it starts with $0.00, and if I type a 5 it shows $0.05, and if I type a 4 it'll show $0.54 and so on. So it will fill in each digit from the right as long as you keep typing. I understand that I'll need to use shouldChangeCharactersInRange but my TextField is in the alertController so it makes things a little difficult and I'm not sure how to approach the logic behind it. Here's what I've got so far

```
@IBAction func myMethod(_ sender: Any) {

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Some words", message: "\n", preferredStyle: .alert)

    myAlert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "TextField1"

    })

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        //some action
    }))

    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Hopefully I explained everything thoroughly enough.
Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all that is missing is setting the delegate of that UITextField. Setting the delegate in the configurationHandler should be enough to correct that.

If your shouldChangeCharactersInRange function is in the parent file, set it as the delegate. Otherwise, create your UITextFieldDelegate class with the methods you need, then set an instance of it as your delegate.

```
class MyTextFieldDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate {
    // Implement shouldChangeCharactersInRange and other delegates here
}
...
// View Controller presenting the alert
var textFieldDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Other stuff here

    // Set your delegate
    textFieldDelegate = MyTextFieldDelegate()
}

...

@IBAction func myMethod(_ sender: Any) {

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Some words", message: "\n", preferredStyle: .alert)

    myAlert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "TextField1"
        textField.delegate = self.textFieldDelegate

    })

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        //some action
    }))

    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```